# Concerns WebRTC.The remote video didn't playing when peers are not in the same network

Tags: webrtc

I'm building a WebRTC chatting web site using java WebSocket.
  It works just fine when users are in the same network(like using the same wifi).But it fails to work when users **aren't** in the same network environment.
  What's really confusing is that the remote video has its src="blob.....".But the video just refuses to play.
  For the STUN server I use stun:stun.l.google.com:19302.
  Can this problem be related to my being in China?
  Thank a lot for reading.
  My project is uploaded in this site.
  https://csckaigi.chinanorth.cloudapp.chinacloudapi.cn/kaigi

Edit 1:
   I just realized that the site is chinese site,so you may need the vpn to access.
   This website is presented by japanese,so i would like to explain how to use this.
   First click the つくる button to create a room , next enter your name then you are in the chatting room .
   Second user should enter the room number(which could copied by first user,or click the room list below.If there's no list,then click the link to refresh),then also enter user's name.Finally the users are suppose to be linked and see each other.

Answer (score 0):

STUN servers are not sufficient. You need a TURN server (and no, there are no 'free' ones) for things to work everywhere, usually around 16% of sessions require this.

See https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/ in the paragraph "Example #1 – My WebRTC app works locally but not on a different network!"